# Enabling AES 256 GCM on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: https, windows-server-2012-r2, ssl

I'd like to enable the use of the AES 256 GCM encryption instead of the AES 256 CBC. We already have ECC certificates based on ECDSA so that pre-requisite has been fullfilled. The certificate has a SHA-256 signature and uses a 256-bit ECC keyset.

The ciphersuite I'd like to use:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384
```

This is our ciphersuite order:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P521,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P521,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256
```

Still when I check the website it says we use TLS 1.2 and ECDHE_ECDSA for key exchange AES_256_CBC encryption and SHA1 for message digest.

I suspect it uses this suite for some reason:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256
```

When I remove that ciphersuite the site has a cipher suite mismatch and won't load the https anymore.
Does anyone know how to enable the ciphersuite? Did I forget to set something in the registry or do I need to do something else to enable that specific suite. Thanks in advance!